# how to fix haskell stack setup failed to compile sanity check on Mac OS 10.14.6

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, macos-mojave

I've somehow messed up my haskell installation on MacOs 10.14.6
I've removed the ~/.stack and ~/.cabal folders and ran `brew uninstall haskell-stack`
I've installed ghc using 
`curl https://get-ghcup.haskell.org -sSf | sh`
and then installed stack using
`brew install haskell-stack`

> `stack --version: Version 2.1.3 x86_64`
>
> `cabal --version: cabal-install version 3.0.0.0`

When I run `stack setup`, I get this:

```
The GHC located at /Users/angudavi/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.6.5/bin/ghc-8.6.5 failed to compile a sanity check. Please see:

    http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/

for more information. Exception was:

Received ExitFailure 1 when running
Raw command: /Users/angudavi/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.6.5/bin/ghc-8.6.5 /private/var/folders/rc/05xmxx2d1z94wfq8gjy5g8640000gn/T/stack-sanity-check-18076106c692e89a/Main.hs -no-user-package-db
Run from: /private/var/folders/rc/05xmxx2d1z94wfq8gjy5g8640000gn/T/stack-sanity-check-18076106c692e89a/

Standard error:

Loaded package environment from /Users/angudavi/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-8.6.5/environments/default
ghc: can't find a package database at /Users/angudavi/.cabal/store/ghc-8.6.5/package.db
```

Comment: The solution seems to be to remove the ~/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-8.6.5 folder.